# AWS Cognito: Methods to Get a List of users?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a web application using Angular 4 (with TypeScript language) front-end side, and using AWS services back-end size.
This application can be only accessed by a group of users (each has its own mail and password). This group of users is defined in AWS Cognito - User Pool.
How can I have the entire list of these users with their properties 
to see her in the frontend? And how do I change their properties only frontend side?

I saw the JavaScript methods for AWS Cognito (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js), but I didn't find anything for what I want to do.

I would like to use some method to show the full list of users with their properties (as seen in the AWS mangement console of Cognito) 
and that always, thanks to another method, my application it's able to edit some information as a "group" of a user.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 6):

Late response but for those who will probably need it :

1. Create a new IAM policy, with the Cognito Listusers allowed
2. the code in JS

   ```js
   const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
        apiVersion: '2016-04-18',
        region: "eu-central-1",
        credentials: Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials)
      });
      var params = {
        UserPoolId: environment.amplify.Auth.userPoolId, /* required */
        AttributesToGet: [
          "email",
        ],
        Limit: 0
      };
      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response
      });
    });
   ```

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error `Validation error detected: Value '100' at 'limit' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have value less than or equal to 60`. if i try to increase the limit i got the above error message.

Comment: @prakashtank according to the doc, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html, Maximum number of results from a single List/Lookup API call  is 60

Comment: @Zecide : yes you are right. I got the solution. I need to pass the paginationToken to get next 60 users and so on...

Answer (score 6):

This function will list the users, just use the aws key and secret, user pool region and id and call the function getUsers(). 
You can use filters in params to do a more specific request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.getUsers= () => {
var params = {
  UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID
  AttributesToGet: [
    'ATTRIBUTE_NAME',
  ],
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AWS.config.update({ region: USER_POOL_REGION, 'accessKeyId': AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 'secretAccessKey': AWS_SECRET_KEY });
    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err)
        }
        else {
            console.log("data", data);
            resolve(data)
        }
    })
});
```

}

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but does this method return the list in a paginated format? For example, if you have over 60 users in your cognito pool, you have to call the listUsers method until you do not receive any pagination tokens in the response?

Comment: I don't use this for almost a year, but I'm almost sure that it returns the whole list of users. I know that you can use filters in the params object but they don't include pagination. Things may have changed, but last year this was the process

Comment: @PedroSilva no it does not return the entire list (At least nowadays), it returns a `PaginationToken` parameter.

Comment: Sorry about it, they might have changed the code. Next weekend I'll try to update the code as I don't use the sdk for 2 years

Comment: This will be the request Object for listUssers API
{
   "AttributesToGet": [ "string" ],
   "Filter": "string",
   "Limit": number,
   "PaginationToken": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string"
}

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Cognito Identity Service Provider [SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html).

The function that you want is `listUsers()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way I've found so far in Typescript.

Calling `.promise()` after `listUsers`, we can wrap a `try catch` block around our API call.

```
import { Result } from '@badrap/result'
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'aws-sdk'
import {
  ListUsersRequest,
  ListUsersResponse,
} from 'aws-sdk/clients/cognitoidentityserviceprovider'

export const listUsers = async (): Promise<Result<ListUsersResponse>> => {
  const identityProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    region: "<your_region>",
    endpoint: "<your_endpoint>",
  })

  const params: ListUsersRequest = {
    UserPoolId: "<your_pool_id>",
  }

  let result: ListUsersResponse = {}

  try {
    result = await identityProvider.listUsers(params).promise()
  } catch (error) {
    return Result.err(error)
  }

  return Result.ok(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get UserPoolId :

To configure your identity pool
Open the Amazon Cognito console . ...

Choose Manage Identity Pools.

Choose the name of the identity pool for which you want to enable Amazon Cognito user pools as a provider.

On the Dashboard page, choose Edit identity pool.

Expand the Authentication providers section.
Choose Cognito.